# Access a div out of the div the function refers to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a problem with the last function. The goal is that when I click on the "suiv" div, the script start a loop with my div ".crea" that is out of the suiv div.

However, the loop `this.div.find('.crea').each(function){}` doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    s = new slider(".galerie");
});

var slider = function (id) {
    var self = this;
    this.div = $(id);
    this.nb = 0;
    this.index = 0;
    this.div.find(".crea").each(function () {
        self.nb++;
        //alert($(this).css("z-index"));
    });
    alert(this.nb);
    this.index = 0;
    this.suiv = this.div.find(".suiv");
    this.prec = this.div.find(".prec");
    this.suiv.click(function () {
        this.div.find(".crea").each(function () {
            //self.index=parseInt($(this).css("z-index"));
            alert("wesh2");
        }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `find('crea')` to `parent('crea').children()`  and it will work.

`find` only goes downwards.

Answer (score 0):

go up to the parent, then use children

```
this.suiv.click(function () {
    this.div.parent.children(".crea").each(function () {
        //self.index=parseInt($(this).css("z-index"));
        alert("wesh2");
    }
    });
}
```